# php error : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

Not able to process this error as I am getting this as my output
    enter code here

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\seo\seo.php on line 161 Notice: Trying to get property
>   of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\seo\seo.php on line 162

and

> Notice:Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\seo\seo.php on
>   line 163 Page Authority:0 Domain Authority:0 External Links:

and this is the code

```
$accessID = " xxxx ";
$secretKey = " xxxxxxxx";
$domain = "$sig";
$expire_in = time() + 500;
$SignIn = $accessID."n".$expire_in;
$binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $SignIn, $secretKey, true);
$urlSafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
$data = "103079215140";
$curlURL = "http://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/?Cols=".$data."&AccessID=".$accessID."&Expires=".$expire_in."&Signature=".$urlSafeSignature;
$Domains = array($domain);
$Domai = json_encode($Domains);
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $Domai
);

$ch = curl_init($curlURL);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );

$result = json_decode($response,true);    
$pageAuthority=round($result[0]->upa,0);
$domainAuthority=round($result[0]->pda,0);
$externalLinks=$result[0]->ueid;

echo "Page Authority:".$pageAuthority."<br/>";
echo "Domain Authority:".$domainAuthority."<br/>";
echo "External Links:".$externalLinks."<br/>";
```

Comment: Can you highlight which line is 161 ?

Comment: what is the value of `$result[0]` ?

Comment: check the $result array, may be it's empty due to parsing problems... what output of print_r($results);

Comment: $pageAuthority=round($result[0]->upa,0);
    $domainAuthority=round($result[0]->pda,0);
    $externalLinks=$result[0]->ueid;

Comment: these three are 161,162 & 163

Comment: $result[0] is empty (noting is printing)

Comment: and the output of print_r($result) is too empty (noting can be seen on screen)

Comment: how to print those values because I have done parsing but still it shows empty and 0 as values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

```
$result = json_decode($response,true);
                                ^^^^ here
```

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So the result will be an array and there will be no objects.

So you need:

```
$result[0]['upa']
// etc.
```

Comment: so what if I remove true

Comment: but I am not able to get the output though i have done parsing

Comment: @sairam You should add the output of `var_dump($result);` to your question.

Comment: thank you now I able to access but the problem is not getting the output though I have done parsing

Answer (score 0):

```
$result[0]
```

is probably not an object.

try using print_r to print the contents of that variable after json_decode.